# Python3 input() floats list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, input, floating-point-precision

I apologise if I am missing something simple here, but I don't understand...

```
list_rho = []
# start some sort of loop
val = input() 
list_rho.extend(val)
```

With this code I am attempting to create a list of rho values: the user inputs a floating point number. This is then added to the list. 
e.g. the user inputs the values `0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.30, 0.35`

However, when I print the list it appears like so:

```
0,  .,  1,  0,  0,  .,  1,  5,  0,  .,  2,  0,  0,  .,  2,  5,  0,  .,  3,  0,  0,  .,  3,  5
```

Clearly, not what I want. The same happens if I try enclosing the input value in quotes or converting the user input to a string first.

Can anyone offer an explanation of what/why this is happening?

N.B. I could use a loop for the values of rho, but, the number of decimal places is important in my end use and I know there is no way of precisely representing 0.1 in base 2...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the strings, you can do:

```
list_rho.extend(val.split(", "))
```

or, to convert to floating point numbers:

```
list_rho.extend(map(float, val.split(", ")))
```

`input` always gives you a string, and `list.extend` iterates over its argument adding each item separately, so `list.extend("foo")` is equivalent to `list.extend(['f', 'o', 'o'])`:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.extend("hello, world")
>>> l
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ',', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']

>>> l = []
>>> l.extend("hello, world".split(", ")) # right
>>> l
['hello', 'world']
```

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns a string.

`list_rho.extend` is expecting a list.

`"0,  .,  1,  0,  0,  .,  1,  5,  0,  .,  2,  0,  0,  .,  2,  5,  0,  .,  3,  0,  0,  .,  3,  5"` is the input string coerced into a list.

```
>>> m = "0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.30, 0.35"
>>> m
'0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.30, 0.35'
>>> n = list(m)
>>> n
['0', '.', '1', '0', ',', ' ', '0', '.', '1', '5', ',', ' ', '0', '.', '2', '0', ',', ' ', '0', '.', '3', '0', ',', ' ', '0', '.', '3', '5']
>>> g = []
>>> g.extend(m)
>>> g
['0', '.', '1', '0', ',', ' ', '0', '.', '1', '5', ',', ' ', '0', '.', '2', '0', ',', ' ', '0', '.', '3', '0', ',', ' ', '0', '.', '3', '5']
```

Comment: `list.extend` expects *an iterable object*, which it gets. It doesn't coerce the `str` to a `list` (Python is strongly-typed, and doesn't implicitly coerce); it iterates over it. The problem here is that iterating over a string is done character-by-character, which isn't how the OP wants to interpret the input.